# How to access the harddisk of the networkprinter Ricoh MP4500?

Tags: network-printer

How to access the harddisk of the networkprinter Ricoh MP4500? The printer is connected to the network, but how do I access the 40GB harddisk? I can't find this with Google, so please help me!

Answer (score 3):

For what? If I recall, the drive is there to store/spool print jobs. You're not supposed to have direct access to it.

If you are really desperate I suppose you could disassemble the system and remove the drive then mount it on another machine, depending on what kind of filesystem it uses (if it's a readable filesystem).

If it's a maintenance issue you should probably call their support line.